# Why can't I download Windows 8 Pro with my MSDN subscription?

Tags: windows-8, msdn

I'm an MSDN subscriber, and as such I have access to all Microsoft applications for development and testing purposes.

However, when I go to download Windows 8 Pro, I find downloads for the following

- Windows 8
- Windows 8 Enterprise
- Debug/Checked builds for the above
- N versions of the above (EC silliness still in effect)
- x86 and x64 versions of the above

and

- Windows 8 Pro VL (x86, x64 and N versions)

But every version of Pro has the following notice

> This product is not available at your subscription level. [Learn More](https://msdn.microsoft.com/subscriptions/buy/default.aspx)

The link leads to a not-very-helpful page with TL;DR and nothing about what "VL" is and why I can't download Pro!

**What is going on?  Why can't I download Windows 8 Pro?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "VL" in "Windows 8 Pro VL" means **"Volume Licensing."**  It is only available for Volume Licensing customers only.  Which you probably aren't, if you're reading this.

Windows 8 Pro is actually bundled within Windows 8, the only difference being that you need to use a different key.

This information is hidden within the **Details** of the "Windows 8 Pro VL" list item. The details of the Windows 8 list item only hints at this fact, saying

> This file contains multiple products. Please refer to your product keys to determine which products are included with your subscription.

#### In order to download and install Windows 8 Pro with your MSDN subscription:

1. Log into MSDN and click the Downloads link
2. Click the link for Windows 8, or view the complete list and search for Windows 8
3. Click the download link for whichever flavor of Windows 8 you prefer (x86, x64, N or Not)
4. As it downloads, click the "Product Keys" button
5. Click the "Get a Key" button for Windows 8 Pro

[image]

Comment: I think the OP's issue is that when you go to the downloads, there's no Windows 8 Pro download that's not a VL.

Comment: @ernie He is the OP ;)

Comment: @Louis Hah . . . definitely a sign that I need to go and get some coffee ;)

Answer (score 2):

The Windows 8 download will allow for both standard and Pro.  The version will be determined by the product key you enter.